# Can not copy text into Clipboard - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to copy **csv** based data (from *SlickGrid*), in to system clipboard.
For small chunks of data it is working fine, but when I have large set of data it is unable to copy into system clipboard.

Here is the code use to perform copy:

```
copyTextToClipboard: function (text) {
    var textArea = document.createElement('textarea');

    // Hide textArea
    textArea.style.position = 'fixed';
    textArea.style.top = 0;
    textArea.style.left = 0;
    textArea.style.width = '2em';
    textArea.style.height = '2em';
    textArea.style.padding = 0;
    textArea.style.border = 'none';
    textArea.style.outline = 'none';
    textArea.style.boxShadow = 'none';
    textArea.style.background = 'transparent';

    textArea.value = text;
    document.body.appendChild(textArea);
    textArea.select();

    try {
        var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
        var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
        console.log('Copying text command was ' + msg);
    } catch (err) {
        alert('Oops, unable to copy to clipboard');
    }

    document.body.removeChild(textArea);
}
```

When I pass large **csv** based text into function, I always get:

> 'Copying text command was unsuccessful'

Sample CSV based text passed into 'copyTextToClipboard' function which fails to copy in clipboard
[image]

Another interesting thing here, is when I use Developer tool and step over each line it properly copies the same data into Clipboard.

Comment: Have you got this error "document.execCommand(‘cut’/‘copy’) was denied because it was not called from inside a short running user-generated event handler."  in your console ?

Comment: No such error on console only 'Copying text command was unsuccessful'

Comment: Can you precise the size of your large set of data ? And which browser are your using ?

Comment: In teams of csv data, ~3000 rows with ~50 columns(http response size is ~2mb), I am using Chrome Version 59.0.3071.104

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it fails normally and in console it gives partial results is because the input is more than one line. Your function is made to accept a normal string without line breaks. I would assume before ES6 you'd have to insert the line breaks with a backslash `\n+` manually or programmatically.

Assuming that you don't care about IE (see [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=template-literals)) [ES6 Template Literals](https://www.keithcirkel.co.uk/es6-template-literals/) takes the humble String to a whole new level. The features used in the following demo are:

- [Literal Syntax](https://www.keithcirkel.co.uk/es6-template-literals/#literal-syntax)

> ```
>   // Conventional String
>    var str = "These &nbsp;&nbsp;words &nbsp;&nbsp;are &nbsp;&nbsp;3 &nbsp;&nbsp;spaces &nbsp;&nbsp;apart"; 
>
>   // Template Literal
>    var tl = `These   words   are   3   spaces   apart`
> ```

- [Expression Interpolation](https://www.keithcirkel.co.uk/es6-template-literals/#expression-interpolation)

> ```
>    var x = 123;
>
>   // Conventional String
>    var str = "Height: " + x + "px";
>
>   // Template Literal
>    var tl = `Height: ${x}px`;
> ```

- [Newline Allowance](https://www.keithcirkel.co.uk/es6-template-literals/#newlines-allowed)

> ```
>  // Conventional String
>    var str = "\n+"
>              "Multiple\n+"
>              "lines\n";
>
>  // Template Literal
>    var tl = `
>             Multiple
>             lines
> ```

---

#### Basic Syntax

- Wrap string in backticks: <kbd>`</kbd> (top left corner of keyboard) instead of quotes: <kbd>"</kbd> or <kbd>'</kbd>
- Wrap variables with `${}` instead of `"+ +"`
- Just use the <kbd>enter</kbd> key instead of `\n+`

---

**Details are commented in demo**

### [Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/s4eUU72PVVjNkMKqo6mi/)

### Demo

```css
textarea {
  width: 90%;
  min-height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  font: inherit;
}

button {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10%
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      font: 400 13px/1.428 Consolas;
    }
    /* This is just to make the console
    || display data that needs no horizontal 
    || scrolling to read.
    */
    
    .as-console {
      word-break: break-word;
    }
    
    button {
      margin-left: 18ch;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <ol>
    <li>Enter text with line breaks.✎</li>
    <li>Click the <kbd>DONE</kbd> button</li>
    <li>Next do one of the following:
      <ul>
        <li>Open a text editor (like Notepad)</li>
        <div>OR</div>
        <li>Go to the auxiliary demo on this answer</li>
      </ul>
      <li>Paste into the text editor or the aux demo</li>
  </ol>
  <p>✎ or you can use a <a href='https://pastebin.com/VZ6Vk4py' target='_blank'>
delimited text file (CSV) of 26 columns and 1000 rows
</a> (right click and open new tab.)</p>

  <textarea id='TA'></textarea>
  <br/>
  <button>DONE</button>
  <br/>

  <script>
    // Reference the <textarea>
    var TA = document.getElementById('TA');

    /* Register #TA to the change event
    || After the user has typed in #TA
    || and then clicks elsewhere 
    || (like the inert <button>)... 
    */
    TA.addEventListener('change', function(e) {

      /* ... the callback function is invoked and
      || the value of the changed element
      || (i.e. e.target = #TA) is passed thru.
      */
      copyTextToClipboard(e.target.value);
    });

    // Define callback function
    function copyTextToClipboard(text) {

      // Create a <textarea>
      var textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
      // Hide new <textarea>
      textArea.style.opacity = 0;

      // Append new <textarea> to the <form>
      document.body.appendChild(textArea);

      /* Wrap the data in backticks:` 
      || (key is top left corner of keyboard)
      || and the variable of data in a dollar
      || sign and curly brackets: ${}
      || The data (a string), is now an 
      || ES6 template literal.
      */
      var str = `${text}`;

      // Assign the new <textArea> value to str
      textArea.value = str;

      /* .select() method gets the content of
      || new <textarea>
      */
      textArea.select();

      /* copy the selected text to the OS
      || clipboard.
      */
      document.execCommand('copy');

      console.log(str);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

### Auxiliary Demo

#### Paste Text from Demo Here

```css
body {
  font: 400 13px/1.428 Consolas
}

textarea {
  width: 90%;
  min-height: 250px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  font: inherit;
}
```

```html
<textarea placeholder='Paste text in this textarea'></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replay and examples, I have one query on this, If that is the case then why does it works properly if I have small number of rows and columns, let say if I limit the rows in http response to 100 rows and perform copy, it just works fine, but when I remove the filter and all rows comes in response it fails to perform copy. We also support for IE11+ for this.

Comment: FYI, If I have debugger in-place  (chrome browser developer tools), it copies large dataset too if I step over each line one by one. So can this be time related issue?

Comment: See what you have on SlickGrid options, there's 3 that might be of specific interest: `enableTextSelectionOnCells: false`, `asyncPostRenderDelay: 50`, `enableAsyncPostRender: false`. Those are at default values.

Comment: Data properly passed into this function.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but what I meant was check your SlickGrid settings https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Grid-Options

Comment: I meant data comes properly in the function but something is wrong with above code only.

Comment: This code will not work for IE11 since it doesn't recognize a template literal. It would need modification to handle a CSV via String. What is the EOL for your CSV. By the image and info you provided, I know that your CSV is ~3000 rows, 50 cols, comma delimited, and String data fields are single quoted. At the 50th column (EOL) what is it? `\n`? `\r\n`?

Comment: I read data from slickgrid and generated csv string in JS only by adding "\n" at the end of each row.